# What is the alternative way to "document.querySelectorAll" in old browsers like ie6, 7?

Tags: javascript, object

My question I think is clear as in the title.
is there another way to **simulate** or **alternative** to use `document.querySelectorAll` on older browsers like `internet explorer 6, 7`.

```
this.elements = [];
var selector, i;
if (document.querySelectorAll) {
    selector = document.querySelectorAll(parameters);
    for (i = 0; i < selector.length; i++) {
        this.elements[i] = selector[i];
    }
} else {
    // Here is the alternative for older browsers.
}
```

**I want the native idea if possible, and I will do everything.**

Comment: An alternative might be to import jQuery (or the lighter sizzle)

Comment: https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill/blob/master/polyfill.js#L652

Comment: IE6 and 7 are the (primary) reason that the Sizzle selector engine is still maintained. It's a non-trivial problem if you really want to support full-blown CSS selectors, and Sizzle is solid and comprehensive.

Comment: webkit is a rather large chunk of that too

Answer (score 1):

I've come across these methods for polyfilling `document.querySelectorAll`:

- **Manual traversing**

  Usually by splitting the selector into parts and running a combination of more basic calls on the individual parts. Often starting out with something like `document.getElementsByTagName('*');` and working off of that.

  Some sources even use fallbacks for non WC3 compatible DOM models, like Netscape's `document.layers` API or IE's `document.all` API, reaching support down to like IE4-5. Searching for `DHTML` will give you more information on these older techniques.
- **CSS behaviours**

  This is an interesting approach since it's usually very compact, but I've heard it's also not very performant.

  In a nutshell CSS behaviours is JS expressions connected to standard CSS, so you can create dynamic CSS rules looking something like this:

  `selector + '{x-qsa:expression(document._qsa && document._qsa.push(this))}';` in order to push the current element (selector hits) unto a newly created `document._qsa`-array which you then use before removing the CSS style from the document.
  You might need to trigger a scroll event to force the browser to use the newly created rule, even if that scroll is by 0px.
- **Web Components, HTC & XUL**

  No, not that that fancy HTML5 Polymer stuff. The original(tm). Web components is by no means anything new. It's usually mentioned under the umbrella term `DHTML`.

  Obviously Netscape and IE had different takes on how to best implement the feature of modular components.  Netscape and up to recently, Mozilla, had support for something called XUL which basically was XML declarations to do all sorts of interesting stuff, create custom elements, run JS and so on.

  IE used HTC-files for pretty much the same thing.  There's examples out there of code which bridges these two API's and lets you run HTC files in Mozilla or XUL files in IE. Dean Edwards homepage is a must for information about the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/chrisjlee/8960575) for this.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a so powerful method, your best chance is to use [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) (the selector engine used by jQuery).